# App security - put secret passwords in a python EXE

Tags: python

I have a python app that I will be distributing to customers via an .exe file. This app will access a mySQL database on an online server. So for the app to access the database it needs an IP address, Username, Password, and database name.

How do I distribute this information with the .exe file so that it's not backward engineerable and not accessed?

Any way of encrypting the password will have to have the decryption method written in the app. So they could just use that

I've looked at environmental variables and other variations on this, but how do I set environmental variables on a computer I don't have access to without including that secret info to set the variables?

At the moment I have them in a local SQlite3 database that the .exe accesses, and I'm giving it out physically and doing online updates that don't include that SQlite3 file but if they lose the USB drive then someone can take it and get the secrets from it.

The sensitive data on the database is encrypted to stop access from outside the app, but if they have the app then it doesn't matter.

What is the safest way to include the secret data?

Comment: Does this help [Python — Separate Code and Sensitive Information Elegantly](https://medium.com/geekculture/python-separate-code-and-sensitive-information-elegantly-ae21cec5fae2)

Comment: Ok, but if I compile it into an .exe isn't the .env file still there and can be unpacked?

Comment: Same question, and I tried the reverse search: what about we try to find a specific string from a given windows binary (.exe)? https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11142/how-to-view-strings-in-an-executable
Seems it's possible but only if the end-user knows the original source code.

Comment: Same question, and I tried the reverse search: what about we try to find a specific string from a given windows binary (.exe)? https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11142/how-to-view-strings-in-an-executable
Seems it's possible but only if the end-user knows the original source code.